# Is it permissible to wash Ihraam-towels with scented products before Hajj?

Tags: practical-islam, fiqh, hajj

It is generally prohibited to wear perfumes and deodorants after you've worn the Ihraam, see this fatwa for example http://www.islamandquran.org/fatwas/using-perfume-deodorant-during-hajj-or-umrah.html.

What if someone washes the towels of Ihraam before Hajj and that leaves behind some fragrance/odor of the detergent or soap? What if you try out the Ihraam before Hajj and body-odor, sweat or perfume can be felt? Would it be OK to use such towels without deodorizing them first?